# How do I sum duplicates of a array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following array.

```
  [0]=>
    array(7) {
        [0]=>31
        [1]=>14
        [2]=>on
        [3]=>receiver
        [4]=>pollin
        [5]=>0000-e8-de-27-176d10
        [6]=>1
    }
  [1]=>
    array(7) {
        [0]=>31
        [1]=>14
        [2]=>on
        [3]=>receiver
        [4]=>pollin
        [5]=>0000-e8-de-27-176d10
        [6]=>5
    }
  [2]=>
    array(7) {
        [0]=>0
        [1]=>17
        [2]=>"on"
        [3]=>"receiver"
        [4]=>"elro_400"
        [5]=>"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"
        [6]=>1
    }
```

I'm trying to sum the value of [6] together, but only if the value of key 0-5 are the same. so the expected result would be this:

```
  [0]=>
    array(7) {
        [0]=>31
        [1]=>14
        [2]=>on
        [3]=>receiver
        [4]=>pollin
        [5]=>0000-e8-de-27-176d10
        [6]=>6
    }
  [1]=>
    array(7) {
        [0]=>0
        [1]=>17
        [2]=>"on"
        [3]=>"receiver"
        [4]=>"elro_400"
        [5]=>"0000-e8-de-27-176d10"
        [6]=>1
    }
```

I tried it myself with `if(array_key_exists($vals[0]&&$vals[1]&&$vals[2]&&$vals[3]&&$vals[4]&&$vals[5],$res))` however this is not working like I thought it would work.

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is remove duplicates if [0] - [5] are the same. But when it removes a duplicate it should sum [6] together.

Simple Example:

```
  [0]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>31
        [1]=>14
        [2]=>1
    }
  [1]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>31
        [1]=>14
        [2]=>4
    }
  [2]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>3
        [1]=>18
        [2]=>1
    }
```

If [0] and [1] are the same, then it well remove the duplicates but add together [2]

So that would result in:

```
  [0]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>31
        [1]=>14
        [2]=>5
    }
  [1]=>
    array(3) {
        [0]=>3
        [1]=>18
        [2]=>1
    }
```

Comment: there's always a `foreach()` loop

Comment: I do not understand how the value of key `6` is calculated. Would not you want to store it in a separate variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$array = [
    ...
];

$resultArray = [];
$length = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $array))
    {
        continue;
    }

    $array1 = $array[$i];
    $values1 = array_slice($array1, 0, -1);

    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $length; $j++)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($j, $array))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $array2 = $array[$j];
        $values2 = array_slice($array2, 0, -1);

        if ($values1 == $values2)
        {
            $array1[6] += $array2[6];

            unset($array[$j]);
        }
    }

    $resultArray[] = $array1;
}

var_dump($resultArray);
```

or

```
$resultArray = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $array1 = $array[$i];
    $values1 = array_slice($array1, 0, -1);

    $length = count($array);

    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $length; $j++)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($j, $array))
        {
            continue;
        }

        $array2 = $array[$j];
        $values2 = array_slice($array2, 0, -1);

        if ($values1 == $values2)
        {
            $array1[6] += $array2[6];

            unset($array[$j]);
        }
    }

    $array = array_values($array);

    $resultArray[] = $array1;
}

var_dump($resultArray);
```

or

```
$resultArray = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    $array1 = $array[$i];
    $values1 = array_slice($array1, 0, -1);

    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++)
    {
        $array2 = $array[$j];
        $values2 = array_slice($array2, 0, -1);

        if ($values1 == $values2)
        {
            $array1[6] += $array2[6];

            unset($array[$j]);

            $j--;
            $array = array_values($array);
        }
    }

    $resultArray[] = $array1;
}

var_dump($resultArray);
```

First solution should be the fastest

I also checked that `isset($array[$i])` works much faster than `arary_key_exists($i, $array)`

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, however your code does not completely work, if there are 6 duplicate arrays all with [6] = 1, then it creates 2 arrays one of [6] = 4 and one of [6] = 2. Like its not fully looping trough them.

Comment: @Dr.Banana thanks for testing, i think i did it without errors. Test it plzz again :)

Comment: I tested it again, both 2 and 3 work properly, the first however is inconsistent. After testing the speed, I noticed that 3 is faster on my setup, so I went with 3. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dr.Banana what do you mean 'inconsistent' ? about speed ?

Comment: The result it outputs, changes with the same data only in a diffrent order, where both 2nd and the 3th work as expected.

Comment: @Dr.Banana same result, but in different order ? i can't repeat bug

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = // your dataset above
$result = array();

foreach ($data as $keyA => $valueA){
    foreach ($data as $keyB => $valueB){
        // showing an explicit way of comparing values, eventually you could use php array_diff or array_diff_key functions
        if ($valueA[0] == $valueB[0] &&
            $valueA[1] == $valueB[1] &&
            $valueA[2] == $valueB[2] &&
            $valueA[3] == $valueB[3] &&
            $valueA[4] == $valueB[4] &&
            $valueA[5] == $valueB[5] &&
            $keyA != $keyB){

            $valueA[6] += $valueB[6];
            $result[] = $valueA;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result); // is now your expected result
```

**Update:** as noted by @vonUbisch, this would only result in the duplicate items. Non-duplicates would be ignored. Perhaps you can explain your final goal, this logic seems really awkard and maybe other approaches could offer a better solution.

**Update 2:**

Still seems as non optimal logic but here it goes

```
$data = array(
    array( 31, 14, 1),
    array( 31, 14, 4),
    array( 3, 18, 1)
);

$mutant = array();
$result = array();

// deconstruct the data set
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    // use the first values as an 'id'
    $id = $value[0] . '.' . $value[1];

    // now we use that id as a key in the result array
    if (array_key_exists($id, $mutant)){
        // if the key exists (a previous dataset with same values existed), we add the last item
        $mutant[$id] += $value[2];
    }else{
        // if the key does not exist, we set the last item
        $mutant[$id] = $value[2];
    }
}

var_dump($mutant);

// array (size=2)
//  '31.14' => int 5
//  '3.18' => int 1

// now we rebuild it
foreach ($mutant as $key => $value){
    // split the key into original values
    $items = explode('.', $key);
    // depending on your data, you might need to iterate over $items here to cast them as ints
    // push the last value 
    $items[] = $value;
    // push sub array into result set
    $result[] = $items;
}

var_dump($result);
// array (size=2)
//   0 => 
//     array (size=3)
//       0 => string '31' * note that value is a string!
//       1 => string '14' (length=2)
//       2 => int 5
//   1 => 
//     array (size=3)
//       0 => string '3' (length=1)
//       1 => string '18' (length=2)
//       2 => int 1
```

Comment: Your result will not match his, look at OP's `$data[1][6]`, but this may be completely irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain it properly. I'm trying to merge the duplicates together, let my give a simple example. I'm not abel to use enters in comments so I posted the example here: http://pastebin.com/SU5YHuTJ

Comment: @Dr.Banana check the second update and let us know if this meets your needs